Are private paternity tests illegal in France?
Wikipedia writes

DNA paternity testing is solely performed on decision of a judge in case of a judiciary procedure in order either to establish or contest paternity or to obtain or deny child support.[19] Private DNA paternity testing is illegal, including through laboratories in other countries, and is punishable by up to a year in prison and a €15,000 fine.[20] The French Council of State has described the law's purpose as upholding the "French regime of filiation" and preserving "the peace of families."[21]

Where [19] references "Art. 16-10 of the Civil Code", [20] "Art. 226-25 to 226-30 of the Penal Code" and [21] The Irish Times
I was able to find (dubious) translations of French law regarding this issue:
penal code 226-25 to 30: and 16-10 of the Civil Code
Penal code translation states

The study of the genetic characteristics of a person for purposes other medical purposes or scientific research, or
their study for medical purposes or scientific research without having obtained the person's prior consent pursuant to the
conditions set out under article 16-10 of the Civil Code, is punished by one year's imprisonment and a fine of €15,000.

This supports the fine and prison terms. However it leave open the question in case of consent. Usully minors (todlers in some paternity cases) can't consent and parent does the parent(s) handle the consenting for them. How does this work in France law?

Are these translations regarding the issue accurate (enough)
Are private paternity tests in France illegal?


Yes, in France, paternity tests may only be conducted as part of judicial proceedings. The translations you found are broadly correct.
You can find a summary of the law on paternity testing on a French government website. There's an automatic English translation. I'll give my own translation below.

Under what legal framework may one perform a paternity test?
Genetic testing is only allowed as part of legal proceedings whose purpose is one of the following:

Establishing or refuting that a person is legally a child of a putative parent;
Claiming or contesting a financial obligation;
Establishing the identity of a deceased person as part of a police inquest.


Furthermore,

When may one request a paternity test from a judge?
You may request a paternity test from a judge if you have opened proceedings to establish or refute a parent-child relationship.
The judge needs a legitimate reason to refuse.

(I don't know what legitimate reasons could be.)

You do not need to provide evidence or clues of the parent-child relationship to request a test.
(…)
A post-mortem biological expertise is possible only if the person had expressly consented while alive.

Article 16-10 of the civil code regulates studies of a person's genetic characteristics. They are only permitted in a small number of cases:

For medical purposes, with the person's express consent.
For scientific purposes, with the person's express consent.
For scientific purposes, if the person had consented to a genetic study for a different purpose, express consent is not required, only non-opposition. (This is subject to a number of conditions listed in article L1130-5.)
For anti-doping purposes, certain analyses are permitted, with the person's express consent (which may be a requirement to enter a competition), as regulated by article L. 232-12-2.

Note that other purposes are not permitted, even with the person's consent.
Article 16-11 of the civil code regulates the identification of a person through their generic characteristics. This is only permitted in a small number of cases:

As part of investigations required for judicial proceedings. In penal matters, this law does not state any limits. In civil matters, this is only permitted if the person consents, and only if the goal is to establish or refute a paternity link, or to claim or contest a financial obligation resulting from a familial link. (As far as I know, the legal term (“subsides”) covers both child support and elder support. I don't know if it also covers cases like a survivor's pension. I don't think it would apply to insurance benefits or inheritance.)
For medical purposes or scientific research, with the person's express consent.
In order to establish the identity of a deceased person whose identity is not otherwise known.
Under certain conditions specified in article L2381-1 of the military code, as part of military operations outside French territory.
For anti-doping purposes, as regulated by article L. 232-12-2 (see above).

Articles 226-25 to 226-30 cover the penalties for violating these laws. The penalties for conducting unauthorized testing rise up to a year in prison and a 15,000€ fine. The penalty for seeking a genetic study or identification is a fine of up to 3,750€ (this is the penalty that would apply if a person under French jurisdiction requests a genetic test abroad).
